# Print out a Single count value for multiple Array items

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, counter

I have this really quick question, im guessing is just staring at me but im not being able to see it. I had to count the number of occurrences of a certain name in an array. I did that using a loop as i was not allowed to use classes, hashmap etc. So i have a 93 names, for example Jake occurs 5 times, i want the out to be:

```
       Jack - 5
```

instead, my program displays

```
       Jack - 5
       Jack - 5
       Jack - 5
       Jack - 5
       Jack - 5
```

I just want it to be printed once, here is my loop for it:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < name.length; counter++)
    {
        String n = (name[counter]);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
            if (name[i].equals(n))
                count++;
        }

        System.out.println(n + " - " + count);
    }
```

ideal output should be:

```
                  Jack - 5
```

i need to print asterisks as output, so i want it to say

```
                 Jack (5) *****
```

Each asterisk represents a occurrence, i know how to print them, and i have put it in my code but it displays

```
                ***** Jack(5)
```

I was wondering how i could i fix that, any ideas?

Comment: name [jack, jack, jack, jack, jack, james, etc], filled with names @SpAm

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment, and expanded in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check next code:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < name.length; counter++)
    {
        String n = (name[counter]);
        int count = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
            if (name[i].equals(n)) {
               flag = false;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
           for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
               if (name[i].equals(n))
                   count++;
           }

           System.out.println(n + " - " + count);
        }
    }
```

Here you checked if selected name not yet in the array (from 0 to counter) than you count how many times it keeps in array and display information.

Comment: Always welcome. If you need have problems with this code I can help.

Comment: As said in my other comment, String is just as much of a class as Arrays is. This answer is less efficient, as it involves three loops.

Comment: yeh, your answer makes more logical sense but if i tell my teacher i wrote that on my own, he'll just laugh at me, this answer is easy for me to explain and passable as my own, but in the future, definitely using yours @SpAm

Comment: @user2291452 You didn't mention in your question that it needed to be at a level that you could code at. This code does however complete the task at hand in the most efficient way you could do it with three loops.

Comment: SpAm don't be so proud about yourself. Different situations have different solution.

Comment: @Petro Gordiyevich I'm sorry if my comment came across as a criticism of your code, that was not my intention. On the contrary, it's nice code, and as I said in my last comment, it's the most efficient way you could do it with three loops. I was simply stating for future viewers of the thread, that the most efficient way would be using the sort method on the Array class as Achintya Jha suggested (which I then wrote code to demonstrate). I did not mean to imply that this was not appropriate code.

Answer (score 1):

You're cycling through each name in the list and checking it each time. Consequently, you're checking the name Jack 5 times, so you get 5 outputs.

As for some reason you're not allowed to use HashMaps, this should solve it:

```
String name[] = new String[]{"jack", "jack", "jack", "james", "jack", "jack", "james"};
ArrayList<String> checkedNames = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int counter = 0; counter < name.length; counter++)
{
    String n = (name[counter]);
    if(!checkedNames.contains(n))
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
            if (name[i].equals(n))
                count++;
        }
        checkedNames.add(n);
        System.out.println(n + " - " + count);
    }

}
```

**Edit**: As you can't use ArrayLists but can sort the array:

```
    String name[] = new String[]{"jack", "jack", "jack", "jack", "jack", "james"};
    String lastName = "";

    Arrays.sort(name);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < name.length; counter++)
    {
        String n = (name[counter]);


        if(!lastName.equals(n))
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
                if (name[i].equals(n))
                    count++;
            }

            System.out.println(n + " - " + count);
        }
        lastName = n;
    }
```

**Second edit**:

Firstly, Arrays is a class built into Java, just as String is:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Secondly, if you want it to print asterisks, then change the System.out.println line to this:

```
System.out.println(n + " (" + count + ")" + new String(new char[count]).replace("\0", "*"));
```

Comment: yeah sorry, forgot to mention, cant use ArrayList and also cant use classes

Comment: Haha, you can't use ArrayList?! What kind of assessment is this? 'How to write the least efficient java possible?'?!
Not using HashMaps, ArrayLists, or Classes is ridiculous, as they are very basic setups in Java designed exactly for situations like this.

Comment: @user2291452 You can sort the array or that is also restricted?

Comment: yeah i know right, been stuck on this for like 3 days. if we could use classes, could have been done last year @SpAm

Comment: thanks! but it keeps saying it cant recognize the count in the System.out.println, and every time i put it back in the loop, im back to where i started... @SpAm

Comment: Did you copy the code correctly? The System.out.println should be exactly where it is in the answer.

Comment: dont worry!!! i found my mistake, i had the brackets in the wrong places, thanks heaps for your help, definatly know how to use ArrayList now. @SpAm

Comment: @SpAm Cool, this is a better answer, I guess :)

Comment: But wait, I just realized, isn't `Arrays` a class? Or is it?

Comment: It's a class built into Java, just as String is.....
The assignment, I would presume, means you can't declare you own classes. If you can't use built in classes in Java, then you can't use Strings either, which would be very unlikely.

Comment: @user2291452 I appreciate the compliment. Incidentally, Petro's answer uses the same variable names as mine, so the println asterisk update, should still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Will you try having a different array (lets say `encouteredNames`) which will store those names whose number of occurrence you've already counted? And then execute only the 'counting' loop only when you've determined that the name to be searched has not been searched previously (or it is still not stored in the `encounteredNames` array).

I'm sure there are better implementations than this, but for the meantime:

```
String[] names = {"Jack", "James", "Charles", "Jack", "Jack", "James"};
String[] encounteredNames = new String[names.length];
int encounteredNamesCount = 0;
for (int counter = 0; counter < names.length; counter++) {
  String name = (names[counter]);
  boolean nameAlreadyEncountered = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < encounteredNames.length && encounteredNames[i] != null; i++) {
    if (encounteredNames[i] == name) {
      nameAlreadyEncountered = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!nameAlreadyEncountered) {
    encounteredNames[encounteredNamesCount++] = name;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
      if (names[i].equals(name)) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(name + " - " + count);
  }
}
```

Comment: how will i go about doing that?

Comment: Okay I'll include it in my answer, for a while :)

Comment: thank you for your help! i'll keep this in a safe place for the next time i need to create another Array! Thanks for all your help! much appreciated :)